# How to Validate Pan Card Number Format Using Jquery Client Side Or C# Server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have to add Pan Card Number in my Application. so that The format is like Ex:BNOPS0157F  first 5 no. should be alphabet then 4 no. should be numeric and the last is alphabet. How Can do that

Comment: One way would be to use a Regular Expression in either [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

use `RegularExpressionValidator` to achieve try this...

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPan"
   ID="regConVal" ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="PAN Number Should be this format 'XXXXX0000X'."
   ForeColor="#ff0000" ValidationGroup="ConVal"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

in javascript

```js
var pan = "ABCDE1234F";
var pan2 = "ASW4578W32"
var patt =/^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/;

console.log(patt.test(pan));
console.log(patt.test(pan2));
```

or in c#

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string checkPanNo = @"^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$";
bool isPANValid = Regex.IsMatch(txtPanNo.Text.ToString().Trim(), checkPanNo);
if (isPANValid == true)
{
     //valid pan number
}
else 
{
    //invalid pan number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use below jQuery for PAN Validation.

$(".txtPANID").keypress(function (e) {
        var textValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which)
        console.log(textValue + char);
        var regexp = /^([A-Z]([A-Z]([A-Z]([A-Z]([A-Z]([0-9]([0-9]([0-9]([0-9]([A-Z])?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/;
        if (!regexp.test(textValue + char))
            e.preventDefault();
        //return false
    });
```